# Proving a stronger version of transitivity law

Tags: real-analysis, logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Given $$(x<y):=\lnot(x\ge y).$$
and the transitivity law of $\le$, i.e.
$$
\mbox{If } (x\le y) \mbox{ AND }  (y\le z),\mbox{ then }( x \le z).
$$

I wish to prove the stronger version of transitivity law of $<$, i.e.
$$
\mbox{If } (x< y) \mbox{ AND }  (y< z),\mbox{ then }( x < z).
$$

My attempt:
$$
(x< y) \mbox{ AND }  (y< z)
$$
$$
\lnot(x \ge y) \mbox{ AND }  \lnot(y\ge z)
$$

$$
\lnot [(x \ge y) \mbox{ OR }  (y\ge z)] \tag{*}
$$
(Perhaps some arguments are needed here about the OR relation ??)
$$
\lnot [(x \ge y) \mbox{ AND }  (y\ge z)] 
$$
Apply the transitivity law of weaker version:
$$
\lnot (x \ge z)
$$
$$
x<z
$$

My Question is: How to argue the intermediate step after the equation (*)?

Comment: Yes, I should've mentioned it.

Comment: If $P\land Q$ implies $R$ we cannot conclude $\neg R$ from $\neg(P\land Q)$. -- Also, to prove transitivity of the negation of $\ge$, you need more properties fo $\ge$ than just transitivity: equality is transitive, yet its negation is not.

Comment: omg, I prove it, at first I thought this was non sensical but I proved your claim

Comment: This may sound like a lie, but it's kinda late here and I wanna rest, (actually very very very late) but I proved the claim in 5 lines.

Comment: You actually want to prove $z < y \land y < x \to z < x$.  The $x,y,z$ in the assumed transitivity law and the $x,y,z$ in the to-prove transitivity law aren't actually the same variables, they are both implicitly universally quantified.

Answer (score 1):

You can go from $\neg (P \lor Q)$ to $\neg (P \land Q)$ using a proof by contradiction:

Assume $P \land Q$

Then $P$

Hence $P \lor Q$

But this contradicts with the given $\neg (P \lor Q)$

So, $\neg (P \land Q)$